# Buscar palavra com exatidão

Tags: python-3.x

Bom pessoal eu tenho um pequeno texto de 1859 palavras onde eu armazenei ele todo em uma variável no formato string. A questão e a seguinte eu tenho esse pequeno código que fiz abaixo:

```
w = wordstring.split()
i = 0
for x in w:
    c = x.find('Be')
    if c == 0:
        i += 1
        print('{} - {}'.format(i, x))
```

Estou querendo buscar a palavra com exatidão que no caso seria 'Be', porém em meu output ele não retorna com essa precisão:

```
1 - Being
2 - Besides,
3 - Be
4 - Before,
```

Existe alguma forma pythonica de eu ter essa exatidão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Código:

```
import re

text = "be besides being bee be, be. before, Be Be. forbe be_ be3 be"
be = re.findall('(\\bbe\\b)', text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(len(be))
print(be)
```

Resultado:

> 6
>   ['be', 'be', 'be', 'Be', 'Be', 'be']

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), o `\\b` faz match em começo ou fim de palavras, no exemplo acima como ele está antes e depois do `be` ele está garantindo que o que está sendo procurado é um `be` que possua antes ou depois dele apenas caracteres de espaço, ponto, vírgula, início fim de linha.

Veja funcionando no Ideone: http://ideone.com/Xa55qs

Comment: expressões regulares salvando vidas

Comment: Perfeito segue meu código no ideone http://ideone.com/QbM3fP
a expressão regular ajudou muito.

Comment: https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cbbe%5Cb&test_string=be%20besides%20being%20bee%20be%2C%20be.%20before%2C%20Be%20Be.%20forbe%20be_%20be3%20be&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0